# Error: The name 'RGGSTAcCode' does not exist in the current context

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

In one of the webpage, I have `RadGrid` inside `FormView` Control
i.e., as below markup:

```
<asp:FormView ID="fvIPRForm" runat="server" DefaultMode="Insert" DataKeyNames="RequestID"
  DataSourceID="odsIPRForm" EnableModelValidation="True" OnItemInserting="fvIPRForm_ItemInserting"
  OnDataBound="fvIPRForm_DataBound" OnItemUpdating="fvIPRForm_Updating" OnItemCommand="fvIPRForm_ItemCommand">

<%-- Create New IPR--%>
<InsertItemTemplate>

<telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultiPage5" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" Width="100%">
<telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView4" runat="server" Width="100%">
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel4" runat="server">

//RadGrid
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RGGSTAcCode" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"....>
 //other code

<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="AccountCode" HeaderText="Account Code">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblAcCode" Text='<%# Eval("AccountCode") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblAcCode2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AccountCode") + " - " + Eval("AccountDescription")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>     

    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlAccountCode" runat="server" Height="200" Width="260"
    AllowCustomText="true" onclienttextchange="OnClientTextChange">
    </telerik:RadComboBox>

    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" OnClientClick="ButtonClicked()" UseSubmitBehavior="true" />&nbsp;                                      
  </EditItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

</telerik:RadGrid>

</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
</telerik:RadPageView>
</telerik:RadMultiPage>

</InsertItemTemplate>

<%-- Edit IPR--%>
<EditItemTemplate>

<telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultiPage5" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" Width="100%">
<telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView4" runat="server" Width="100%">
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel4" runat="server">

//RadGrid
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RGGSTAcCode" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"....>
 //other code

<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="AccountCode" HeaderText="Account Code">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblAcCode" Text='<%# Eval("AccountCode") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblAcCode2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AccountCode") + " - " + Eval("AccountDescription")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>     

    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlAccountCode" runat="server" Height="200" Width="260"
    AllowCustomText="true" onclienttextchange="OnClientTextChange">
    </telerik:RadComboBox>

    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" OnClientClick="ButtonClicked()" UseSubmitBehavior="true" />&nbsp;                                      
  </EditItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

</telerik:RadGrid>

</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
</telerik:RadPageView>
</telerik:RadMultiPage>

</EditItemTemplate>

 <%-- View IPR--%>
<ItemTemplate>

<telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultiPage5" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" Width="100%">
<telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView4" runat="server" Width="100%">
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel4" runat="server">

//RadGrid
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RGGSTAcCode" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"....>
 //other code

<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="AccountCode" HeaderText="Account Code">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblAcCode" Text='<%# Eval("AccountCode") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblAcCode2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AccountCode") + " - " + Eval("AccountDescription")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>   

    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlAccountCode" runat="server" Height="200" Width="260"
    AllowCustomText="true" onclienttextchange="OnClientTextChange">
    </telerik:RadComboBox>

    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" OnClientClick="ButtonClicked()" UseSubmitBehavior="true" />&nbsp;                                      
  </EditItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

</telerik:RadGrid>

</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
</telerik:RadPageView>
</telerik:RadMultiPage>

</ItemTemplate>

</asp:FormView>
```

Now, I try to get the `RadGrid` -- `EditItemTemplate` -- `Button` control
inside JavaScript to make it visible true/false based on **text** length that user enter in `RadComboBox`.

Below is my JavaScript:

```
<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function OnClientTextChange(sender, eventArgs) {
            //alert("You typed " + sender.get_text());

            var len = sender.get_text().length;
            alert(len);

            var form = $find("<%#RGGSTAcCode.ClientID%>").get_masterTableView();
            alert(form);

        }
</script>
```

When I run my web page, I always get below **error**:

> The name 'RGGSTAcCode' does not exist in the current context

I tried to change the JavaScript code as below:

```
var form = document.getElementById('<%=fvIPRForm.FindControl("RGGSTAcCode").ClientID%>'); 
var masterTable = form.get_masterTableView();
alert(masterTable);
```

but then I get `[object Object]` in "alert". What is wrong in my code?

### Edit

Tried below solution, all working except Buttons are not disabled/enabled inside if/else:

```
function onTextChange(sender, args) {
                //alert("You typed " + sender.get_text());
                var len = sender.get_text().length;
                alert(len);

                var comboID = sender.get_id();
                var btnSearchID = comboID.replace("ddlAccountCode", "btnSearch");
                alert("Alert 1: " + btnSearchID); //getting : contentplaceholder_fviIPRForm_RGGSTAcCode_btnSearch

                var btnCtrl = $get(btnSearchID);
                alert("Alert 2: " + btnCtrl); //getting : [object HTMLInputElement]

                if (len > 5) 
                {
                    alert("greater");

                    btnCtrl.set_enabled(true);
                    btnsearch.set_enabled(true); // enable search button                    
                }
                else 
                {
                    alert("less");

                    btnCtrl.set_enabled(false);
                    btnsearch.set_enabled(false); // disable search button                   
                }               
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is working fine based on my requirement:

```
function onTextChange(sender, args) {
                var len = sender.get_text().length;
                //alert(len);

                var comboID = sender.get_id();
                var btnSearchID = comboID.replace("ddlAccountCode", "btnSearch");
                var btnCtrl = document.getElementById(btnSearchID);

                if (len >= 5) 
                {
                    btnCtrl.disabled = false;
                    //btnCtrl.style.display = "";
                }
                else 
                {
                    btnCtrl.disabled = true;
                    //btnCtrl.style.display = "none";
                }               
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be the answer you want....
Not the best but is working..

.aspx

```
    <asp:FormView ID="fv" runat="server" DefaultMode="Insert" OnDataBound="fv_DataBound">
        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultiPage5" runat="server" 
             SelectedIndex="0" Width="100%">
                <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView4" runat="server" Width="100%">
                    <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel4" runat="server">
                        <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" 
                         AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                         OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource">
                            <MasterTableView>
                                <Columns>
                                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Acc">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"
                                             Text='<%# Eval("Acc") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlAccountCode" 
                                             runat="server" Height="200" Width="260"
                                             AllowCustomText="true" 
                                             OnClientTextChange="onTextChange">
                                                <Items>
                                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Gg" />
                                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Gg1" />
                                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Gg3" />
                                                </Items>
                                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
                                            <telerik:RadButton ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                </Columns>
                            </MasterTableView>
                        </telerik:RadGrid>
                    </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
                </telerik:RadPageView>
            </telerik:RadMultiPage>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
```

Javascript

```
    <telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="rcb" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function onTextChange(sender, args) {
                var grid = $find('<%=fv.FindControl("RadGrid1").ClientID %>');
                var gridMasterData = grid.get_masterTableView();
                var dataItem = gridMasterData.get_dataItems();
                var length = dataItem.length;

                // Loop
                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    // Find Control
                    var comboBox = dataItem[i].findControl("ddlAccountCode");

                    // Check
                    if (comboBox != undefined) {
                        if (sender.get_id() == comboBox.get_id()) {
                            // Find Button
                            var btn = dataItem[i].findControl("btnSearch");
                            var item = sender.get_text();

                            // Check
                            if (item.length > 5) {
                                if (btn != undefined) btn.set_visible(true);
                            }
                            else btn.set_visible(false);

                            break;
                        }
                        else
                            continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Variable
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Acc");

        dt1.Columns.Add("a");

        // Loop
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            dt.Rows.Add("a " + i);

        dt1.Rows.Add("AAAA");



        ViewState["Data"] = dt;

        // Bind
        fv.DataSource = dt1;
        fv.DataBind();

        dt.Dispose();
        dt1.Dispose();
    }
}

protected void fv_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // FindControl
    RadGrid RadGrid1 = fv.FindControl("RadGrid1") as RadGrid;

    // Check
    if (RadGrid1 != null)
    {
        RadGrid1.DataSource = ViewState["Data"] as DataTable;
        RadGrid1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    RadGrid rg = fv.FindControl("RadGrid1") as RadGrid;

    // Check
    if (rg != null)
    {
        rg.DataSource = ViewState["Data"] as DataTable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. Please note that the RadComboBox and Button is inside `EditItemTemplate` of `RadGrid`. I tried your code and I am getting `alert("dataItem :" +dataItem);` as blank/null. Due to this `alert(length);` is also blank. Also, I tried 1 more method(please check **Edit** section in my posted question), there button is not getting disabled inside IF/ELSE. 
Please let me know where I am wrong ? Please reply

Comment: Also, in ur code when I hardcode `length=5` in "for" loop, I get error: `cannot read property 'findcontrol' of undefined`. Please let me know what is wrong in my code ? Please reply

Comment: Change your `var btnCtrl = $get(btnSearchID);` to `var btnCtrl = $find(btnSearchID);`. then `findcontrol` is case sensitive... `findControl()` will only work for `Telerik Control only`. Then what are you expected... your code above is enable below is visible how can it work...

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. I changed `var btnCtrl = $find(btnSearchID);` and I get null in alert box. Made changed in my **Edit** as well. For my 2nd reply, please ignore the `findcontrol` (typing mistake) , its `findControl`. Please reply what shall I change in your code (based on my errors) to make it work ?

Comment: nvm the `findcontrol` your button is not `telerik control` so just use `document.getElementById(btnSearchID);` then `btnCtrl.disabled = false;` or `btnCtrl.disabled = true;`

Comment: When I use `var btnCtrl = document.getElementById(btnSearchID);` , in alert(btnCtrl) I get `[object HTMLInputElement]`. 
Also, I tried your suggested solution as well, but in alert(dataItem) I get blank/null , due to this alert(length) is 0. when I hardcode length=5 in for loop I get this error `cannot read property 'findControl' of undefined`. Please reply for both.

Comment: You just use back your code as the "Edit Post". Since you already used replace method why you need to loop... So you dont need the dataItem anymore. Just use the document.getElementById(for your button only). Then use javascript to disabled the button but not using telerik javascript to disabled it